# System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any

Tags: c#

I am getting an error with this code:

```
if (!App.selectedPhrases.Any())
```

Here's the error message:

> Xamarin Exception Stack: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be
>   null. Parameter name: source   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource]
>   (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x0000d] in
>   :0   at
>   Japanese.DeckTabViewModel.ShowFirstMessageAsync () [0x00029] in
>   <75f30b75b8d1435e80e8b7703a671cac>:0   at
>   Japanese.DeckTabViewModel.OnAppearing () [0x0006c] in
>   <75f30b75b8d1435e80e8b7703a671cac>:0   at
>   Japanese.DeckTabPage.OnAppearing () [0x0006d] in
>   <75f30b75b8d1435e80e8b7703a671cac>:0   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__7_0
>   (System.Object state) [0x00000] in
>   <3ad100fe60d44e1c8a81197ba1997e7e>:0   at
>   Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0 () [0x00000]
>   in :0   at
>   Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in
>   :0   at
>   Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00009] in :0   at
>   (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.34(intptr,intptr)

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be happening, how I could find the exact line number in the exception and then also how I could resolve this.

In particular I am confused as to why the stacktrace doesn't show any line number. Does anyone know why this is?

One more question.  How can I avoid the use of a "!" here as I find this very confusing.

Comment: Most likely `App.selectedPhrases` is null

Comment: for the first question, use `App.selectedPhrases?.Any()` for the second question, you can do `if(App.selectedPhrases.Any() == true)` or `if(App.selectedPhrases.Any() != true)` ..etc.

Comment: While an exact line number was not given, the error hints at where the issue originates `Japanese.DeckTabViewModel.ShowFirstMessageAsync () => Japanese.DeckTabViewModel.OnAppearing () =>  Japanese.DeckTabPage.OnAppearing()` Do you have an `async void` somewhere there? It could be executing on a separate thread before the member has been set. This leads me to believe this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to check for `null` on `selectedPhrases`, 
This can be done  easily with the

[Null-conditional operator `?.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

> Available in C# 6 and later, a null-conditional operator applies a
>   member access, ?., or element access, ?[], operation to its operand
>   only if that operand evaluates to non-null; otherwise, it returns
>   null.

However because of *lifting*, you will have to explicitly specify `false` on the *if condition*

```
if(App.selectedPhrases?.Any() == false)
```

or if you want to check check for `null` explicitly as part of the condition, you can use *short circuiting* ([Conditional logical OR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#conditional-logical-and-operator-))

> The conditional logical OR operator ||, also known as the
>   "short-circuiting" logical OR operator, computes the logical OR of its
>   operands. The result of x || y is true if either x or y evaluates to
>   true. Otherwise, the result is false. **If x evaluates to true, y is not
>   evaluated**.

```
if(App.selectedPhrases == null || !App.selectedPhrases.Any())
```